# Fuelux - Datepicker style not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fuelux

Im trying to use the [fuelux datepicker](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#datepicker) but its style is not working as its shown in the documentation. What am I doing wrong here?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fa0oxgn3/)

I have the css loading for both bootstrap and fuelux in my code properly and the js is working too:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.2.0/css/fuelux.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

I'm sorry. There appears to be a bug in the [fuelux.min.css](http://www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.2.0/css/fuelux.min.css) file.

Please use [fuelux.css](http://www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.2.0/css/fuelux.css) until this is fixed. I will create an issue on GitHub.

[UPDATED] Fuel UX 3.2.1 has been released with [fuelux.min.css](http://www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.2.1/css/fuelux.min.css) fixed. Thanks for the quick feedback!